# Where does QWindow* gets passed to a QML component

Tags: qt, qml

I try to update/inherit from QWinTaskbarButton so that I can control the color shown by the component on task app icon progress as that is not exposed currently (at least in QT 5.15)

I cannot figure out looking into the code how the parent is passed when instantiating this component from QML:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The *parent* constructor argument that TaskbarButtonWrapper sees is nullptr. What should I do so that my new component receives a proper parent object as it seems the library already implemented QWinTaskbarButton is receiving something valid on QML instantiation ?

```
I instantiate my new component TaskbarButtonWrapper in QML like this:
    // inside the QML file of the main window
    TaskbarButtonWrapper {
       id: taskbarButton
    }
```

Comment: *The parent constructor argument that TaskbarButtonWrapper sees is nullptr.* -- How do you know? Did you run it in a debugger? Are you passing a parent in when you construct the object? You haven't shown us the code when you call the constructor.

Comment: @JarMan I set a breakpoint under debugger in the cpp implementation and saw it. I updated the usage from QML

Comment: I'm guessing you're on the wrong way. Apart from the fact that changing the standard behavior is wrong. You have to do that in QtQuick way, at least I see they create a QML component  which is a descendant of QQuickItem [around the WinTaskbarButton](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwinextras.git/tree/src/imports/winextras/qquicktaskbarbutton.cpp?h=5.15#n121), not instantiate that directly